# Wordpress High CPU Usage

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I received an email from my hosting provider (hostgator) telling me that: "Your account has been placed under resource restriction!  Your account has exceeded our extreme usage threshold for several hours..."

Logs of the CPU usage are provided below:
CPU seconds used in the past hour: 3318.56999999999, 93% CPU

`Tue Sep  3 21:01:10 CDT 2013
Running Processes:
user    21172 60.0  0.1 340216 50288 ?        RN  21:01  0:00 /usr/bin/php /home1/user/public_html/index.php`

Running Queries:
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  USER: user_db
    DB: name_db
  STATE: Sorting result
  TIME: 0
COMMAND: Query
  INFO: SELECT ID, post_title, meta_value FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id AND post_status='publish' AND post_type='post' AND meta_key='_liked' ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC LIMIT 10

Can anyone explain me what is this and how to solve?

Comment: do the access logs for the period show anything unusual?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should have to install " WP Overview (lite) Footer Memory Usage " plugin on your server and you can check it...

And also install " W3 Total Cache " and cache your files and images from the server. You can increase a speed of your side with this plugin.

Comment: I use shared hosting. Can I install WP Overview (lite) Footer Memory Usage on my site? Also i use WP super Cache.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's not your site that is the problem/cause.  HostGator's shared account performance has been poor for sites that rely on MySQL even since their purchase by EIG and subsequent server migration in late 2013.

I speak from experience, as I host 40+ WordPress blog with HostGator, and have seen performance issues with almost all of them, despite each having different plugins, traffic levels and themes.

Find another (non EIG) web host, and if you can afford it upgrade to a VPS that can scale based on your needs as shared hosting is always a gamble.